# how to repeat background image around centered main content with css3

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I've been trying to achieve a certain look on an HTML page with CSS3 (taking baby steps with Foundation framework). I would like main content to be flanked by a repeating background image (sort of like this public example: [public site](http://gonzalolira.blogspot.com/)- i.e. The blogger's content is "surrounded" by his image. Here is my app.css file:

```
body { 
  background: url('../img/TCBlogo-beta.jpg');
}
```

My image is 388px by 261px here: [image: image for my test]

Here is my home.html (the repeating jpg file does not "flank" the div on each side; it "overlays" the content):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin 
    urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin 
    urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
    </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin 
    urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin 
    urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
    </p>
    </div>
  <div class="large-4 columns">
      <h1>Welcome to my site</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 columns ">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin 
    urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin 
    urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
    </p><p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin 
    urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin 
    urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
    </p><p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin 
    urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada semper mi, id sollicitudin 
    urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[1](http://gonzalolira.blogspot.com/)

Comment: By overlay you mean to be on top of the text?

Comment: Yes. For example, if I were to change my css to background-color: yellow in the body above, then the entire wide-screen is yellow. I want the div's to be white and have the background image (or color) fill the left and right margins. I'm sure I am overlooking something very basic. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS do, where `width:***px;` is your desired width in pixels that you want your "white divs" to be:

```
body{background-color:yellow;}
.row{width:***px;margin:0 auto;background-color:white;}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFruS/) for an example.

Comment: Thank you. You are great to respond. A similar approach actually came to me overnight too. In hindsight, my question was quite stupid. Thank you for your time. I must learn more about CSS and JSFiddle too.

Comment: Yeah, my pleasure!  Message me whenever you need help :)